# Conda does not set up properly path for JDK for pyjnius

Tags: windows, windows-10, conda, pyjnius

I have installed [pyjnius](https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) with conda. However, when I try to import pyjnius it fails

```
> from jnius import autoclass

File
 "C:\Users\OEM\Miniconda3\envs\example-env\lib\site-packages\jnius\__init__.py",
 line 12, in <module>
     from .jnius import *  # noqa ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Together with pyjnius conda installs also openjdk. Next, pyjnius looks for `jvm.dll` in one of `PATH` directories. DLL could be found in

> C:\Users\OEM\Miniconda3\pkgs\openjdk-11.0.1-1017\Library\bin\server

but conda does not include it in `PATH`. It adds another folder in `PATH`:

> C:\Users\OEM\Miniconda3\envs\example2-env\Library\jre\bin\server

while this directory is missing: JRE has not been installed, only JDK. I can, obviously, include first directory in my `PATH`, however, this would bypass conda virtual environments concept. How can I solve this problem in an elegant way?

Here's `environment.yml` to reproduce the problem:

```
name: example-env
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.7
  - Cython
  - pyjnius
```

Next, I create and activate as follows:

```
conda env update --file environment.yml
conda activate example-env
```

Comment: JDK is a superset of JRE, so I don't see why that would be an issue.